# how to add context menu to WebBrowser wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

Is it possible to add Context Menu to WebBrowser in WP7?(like IE)

silverlight toolkit Context Menu not support WebBrowser!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser does not support context menus and doesn't function like other Silverlight controls. Therefore, it's not possible to directly add a ContextMenu. However, there are workarounds possible. One of them is to use the InvokeScript method. You should read [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/75627/513692.aspx). Apparently the code at the bottom of the thread works.
Note: `GINternet` is the WebBrowser control's name, so you'll need to change that to yours.

```
public void AttachContextMenu()
{
      try
      {
           if (GINternet.IsScriptEnabled)
           {
                GINternet.InvokeScript("execScript", "function FindParentLink(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentLink(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction FindParentImage(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentImage(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction HandleContextMenu() \r\n{\r\n\tvar linkItem = FindParentLink(event.srcElement);\r\n    var imageItem = FindParentImage(event.srcElement);\r\n    var notifyOutput = '';\r\n    if (linkItem != null) if (linkItem.href != null) notifyOutput += linkItem.href;\r\n    if (imageItem != null) if (imageItem.src != null) notifyOutput += imageItem.src;\r\n    if (notifyOutput != '')\r\n        window.external.notify(notifyOutput);\r\n    else\r\n\t\twindow.external.notify('NOTLINKIMG');\r\n}");
                GINternet.InvokeScript("execScript", "document.oncontextmenu = HandleContextMenu;");
           }
      }
      catch
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: Very very thanks
But I have a problem
How to show the context menu under my click position
I Use this:
`<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1">
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
<toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu1">
<toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" />
</toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</phone:WebBrowser>`

and context menu shows on top of the page!!!

Comment: @sma6871 can you give more details how you managed to get it to work? I have a webbrowser control that displays a single image. I want to display a context menu that says "Save Image", if a user holds his finger on it.

Comment: @zyash just copy function of keyboardP answer to your code and call it when your page is loaded. Now, when a user holds his finger on webbrowser control **ScriptNotify** will be fired. The link of image is in the e.value.