# MenuContext not show when holding in WebBrowser Component Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

When holding in Internet Explorer app, it show a menu context for extra actions(open in new tab, copy link, share link) like this pictures
    ![Internet Explorer][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNv9.png
```

But when i add a WebBrowser Component in my Windows Phone 8 project, holding a link but it not show anything. This is xaml code of WebBrowser Component

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="0" Background="Transparent" />
```

Any one can tell my why and how to fix this?

I tried this but not work

XAML

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="0" Background="Transparent">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu1">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </phone:WebBrowser>
```

C#

```
public void AttachContextMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            if (webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled)
            {
                webBrowser.InvokeScript("execScript", "function FindParentLink(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentLink(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction FindParentImage(item) \r\n{\r\n\tif (!item.parentNode)\r\n\t\treturn null;\r\n\tif (item.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn item;\r\n\t} \r\n\telse \r\n\t{\r\n\t\treturn FindParentImage(item.parentNode);\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction HandleContextMenu() \r\n{\r\n\tvar linkItem = FindParentLink(event.srcElement);\r\n    var imageItem = FindParentImage(event.srcElement);\r\n    var notifyOutput = '';\r\n    if (linkItem != null) if (linkItem.href != null) notifyOutput += linkItem.href;\r\n    if (imageItem != null) if (imageItem.src != null) notifyOutput += imageItem.src;\r\n    if (notifyOutput != '')\r\n        window.external.notify(notifyOutput);\r\n    else\r\n\t\twindow.external.notify('NOTLINKIMG');\r\n}");
                webBrowser.InvokeScript("execScript", "document.oncontextmenu = HandleContextMenu;");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AttachContextMenu();
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631746/how-to-add-context-menu-to-webbrowser-wp7.

Comment: i add AttachContextMenu() (in that link) to webBrowser_LoadCompleted funtion but nothing change

Comment: Did you handle that event in your code? You have to show that context menu yourself now.

Comment: @ToniPetrina i have edited questions as above

Comment: You haven't handled notifications *from* the browser when it sends you the link. And you haven't added `ContextMenu` to your XAML. You have to completely recreate the context yourself.

Comment: @ToniPetrina can you give the the right code, i tried as above but not work

Comment: Sorry, but I never tried that myself, I merely sent you what I've found the other people did.

Comment: Here is answer for you. It is working on Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25502155/1852089][1]